# Change the text for buttons when taking picture via Camera using UIIMagePickerController

Tags: ios, button, camera, xamarin, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the UIImePickerController to take a picture from the camera.
I'm using the Camera helper listed by Xamarin.

It works perfectly well, but I need to change the button text "Cancel", "Use Photo" and "Retake Photo" to German.

There is almost no documentation regarding this.
Can you please help.
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't `UIImagePickerController` inherit from your app's localization automatically?

Comment: It isn't doing that. That's the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Project properties, Go iOS Build > Advanced > Internationalization

Select the necessary region. In my case it was west.

If it doesn't work, Clean the project, manually delete the bin and obj folders and do a build.